# How to apply Media Queries on a DIV using Javascript or CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I am having a problem with a **JavaScript** driven web app, I want the user to change the size of a div using a slider but the problem is that the media queries of **CSS** do not apply on the width of a div so is there any way using **JavaScript** or **CSS** to apply **CSS** media queries on the width of a div and not on the width of the entire window???

Comment: can you post some code, its hard to understand without code

Comment: You need to change the div width with js, not media query

Comment: Media queries are designed for changing styles based on browser width. You are trying to change the width of a div based on a slider which requires javascript. Knowing that, I suggest you give it a try and come back when you run into a specific issue with the js code

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, there are properties called `innerWidth`, `innerHeight`, `outerHeight`, and `outerWidth` for `window` object. For HTML elements, there's `offsetHeight` and `offsetWidth`. You can use templating in javascript for automatic resizing of `width` and `height` in CSS, like so:

`HTMLElement.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px'`

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it is hard to say.  However, contextually you can just update an existing `<style>` element `textContent` to contain what you are after.

Something like this:

```
document.querySelector('style').textContent +=
    "@entire window and (inner-width:400px) { div { color: blue; }}"
```

Obviously, you need to update the above code to fit your code (I just gave the syntax essentially).

Let me know your results.

Comment: You misread the question, the OP thought media query can be applied to a div instead of an entire page which is not what media queries are designed for

Comment: @Huangism Oh I see - I did not consider OP was focused on applying to DIV - yes of course media queries are not designed for that purpose...Thanks for the feedback!